# Subsetting matrices

Tags: r

Considering following vector res and matrix team.
the vector res represent indices, and I require to extract only those names whose index number is in vector res and gender="F".

I need to do this in R and as I am a newbie to R, could not resolve this.

```
res
[1]  2 12 16  5  6 19 17 14  9  4
team
names       genders
[1,] "aa"           "M"       
[2,] "ab"            "M"       
[3,] "al"            "M"       
[4,] "alp"           "M"       
[5,] "amr"           "F"       
[6,] "and"           "M"       
[7,] "an"            "M"       
[8,] "anv"           "F"       
[9,] "as"            "M"       
[10,] "ed"            "M"       
[11,] "neh"           "F"       
[12,] "pan"           "M"       
[13,] "poo"           "F"       
[14,] "ra"            "M"       
[15,] "roh"           "M"       
[16,] "shr"           "F"       
[17,] "sub"           "M"       
[18,] "val"           "M"       
[19,] "xi"            "M"
```

Comment: i need to get the names of those indices in vector res that map to "F" in gender. So for the above data, i need to extract "shr" as it is in vector res, and in matrix team at [16,] is "F" in gender.

Comment: team[res,][team[res,]$genders=='F',]

Comment: @AndresT - just to note - that solution will require conversion of the matrix to a data.frame first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

You could first pick which rows are in `res`:

```
team$names[res]
```

Then you can pick which ones have `gender` being `"F"`:

```
team$names[res][  team$genders[res]=="F"   ]
```

Note that `team$genders[res]` picks out the genders corresponding to the rows in `res`, and then you filter to only accept those that are female.

---

If you liked, you could do it the other way round:

```
team$names[  team$genders=="F" & (1:nrow(team) %in% res) ]
```

Here `team$genders=="F"` is a logical vector of length `nrow(team)`, being `TRUE` whenever the gender is "F" and `FALSE` otherwise.

The `1:nrow(team)` generates row numbers, and `1:nrow(team) %in% res` is `TRUE` if the row number is in `res`.

The `&` says "make sure that the gender is "F" AND the row number is in `res`".

---

You could even do `which(team$genders=="F")` which returns a vector of row numbers for females, and then do:

```
team$names[ intersect(  which(team$genders=="F") , res ) ]
```

where the `intersect` picks row numbers that are present in *both* `res` and the females.

---

And I'm sure people with think of more ways.

Comment: I think the `intersect()` method is the cleanest and most readable solution, but it is nice to see other options.

Comment: These all appear to be acting as if the team object is a data.frame where it was stated to be a matrix.

Comment: Thanks DWin.. but i got error that $ is not for atomic vectors.. No idea what that means!

Comment: @pdb - it means that your `team` is not a list or data.frame. `$` does not work on numeric vectors or matrices, only on lists and other "recursive" objects. In my answer I use `[` instead of `$` which works on both.

Comment: Oh, I apologise. I didn't read your post properly and assumed you had a data frame (which allows `dataframe$columnname`) not a matrix ( `matrix[,'columnname']`). The logic of my answer is still the same but you'll have to convet `$colname` to `[,'colname']` - you may prefer @Tommy's answer (you're welcome to change the "accepted answer" after the fact).

Answer (score 7):

This should work if your `team` is either a `matrix` or a `data.frame`:

```
# emulate your data
team <- data.frame(names=LETTERS, genders=rep(c("M","F"), 13))
res <- 10:26

team[intersect(res, which(team[,"genders"]=="F")), "names"]
#[1] J L N P R T V X Z
#Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

# Try with a matrix instead of data.frame
team <- as.matrix(team)
team[intersect(res, which(team[,"genders"]=="F")), "names"]
#[1] "J" "L" "N" "P" "R" "T" "V" "X" "Z"
```

The basic idea is to get the indices of the "F" gender rows (using `which`) and then use the set operation `intersect` to AND it with your `res` indices. There are also `union` and `setdiff` variants that can be useful at times.

Comment: Sorry Tommy, didnt work, gave error:Error: subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 2):

```
team <- structure(c("aa", "ab", "al", "alp", "amr", "and", "an", "anv", 
"as", "ed", "neh", "pan", "poo", "ra", "roh", "shr", "sub", "val", 
"xi", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M"), .Dim = c(19L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("names", "genders")))

 team[,"names"][ intersect(  which(team[,"genders"]=="F") , res ) ]
#[1] "amr" "shr"
 team[,"names"][ team[,"genders"]=="F" & 1:NROW(team) %in% res  ]
#[1] "amr" "shr"
```